# 80% of population is vaccinated and 25% of infected had received the vaccine, what is the efficacy of the vaccine?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

80% of population is vaccinated and 25% of infected had received the vaccine before being infected, what is the efficacy of the vaccine?

Lets denote

$\Pr(V) = 0.8$ (V="vaccinated")

$\Pr(I)$ is not given (I = "infected")

$\Pr(V\mid I) = 0.25$

What is the efficacy of the vaccine?

I am dumbfounded as I need to have either $\Pr(I)$ or $1-Pr(I)$ to solve any probability question related to this problem. For example $\Pr(I \mid V) = \frac{Pr(V \mid I)Pr(I)}{Pr(V)}$ which can be simplified because we know both $Pr(V)$ and $Pr(V \mid I)$: $Pr(I \mid V)=\frac{0.25*Pr(I)}{0.8}$, but then we hit brick wall as Pr(I) is not given.

Comment: How do you quantitatively define efficiency? Also, surely you mean $P(V|H)=0.25$.

Comment: Pr(V | H) =0.25, Pr(!V | H) = 0.75, Pr(V) = 0.8, Pr(!V) = 0.2. I don't know what is vaccine efficiency, but maybe it is something like Pr(H | !V) / Pr(H | V), which could be calculated wih Bayes formula.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "efficacy" or "effectiveness"?  Can you provide a link to the use of term "efficiency" in this context?

Comment: I assume efficacy is correct term here. English is my second language. I'll submit this question to language exchange as well.

Answer (score 5):

*My response to the OP's concluding paragraph:*

It is a **common misconception** that vaccine efficacy means the probability $P(I^c|V)$ of non-infection given that one is vaccinated.

Rather, **vaccine efficacy** measures the ***increase in protection* conferred by the vaccine**.

Your risk $P(I^c|V)$ of non-infection depends on the disease prevalence, and your exposure, safety measures, state of health, and vaccination status; **vaccine efficacy** (and vaccine effectiveness, for that matter) is not measuring this probability!

(Vaccine effectiveness is with reference to real-world data, whereas vaccine efficacy refers to clinical-trial results.) Note that none of this discussion, including what follows, takes immunity duration into consideration.

---

*My Answer to main Question:*

The technical definition of **vaccine efficacy** is given at the bottom of my Answer [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/97797/63723). Note that this formula is based on an equal number of vaccinated and unvaccinated study subjects, which is *not* the case in your problem.

But we can adapt: based on your given setup/context,

- there are $4$ times as many vaccinated as there are unvaccinated
  subjects;
- $25\%$ of the infected subjects had been vaccinated prior.

Thus, if the vaccine effectiveness is exactly $0\%$ (in other words, the vaccine has no effect), then we expect that among the infected, there will $4$ times as many vaccinated as there are unvaccinated subjects.

Since the actual multiple is $\frac{25}{75}=\frac13$ instead of $4,$ then the **relative risk** $R$ is $$\frac{\frac13}4=8.33\%,$$ so the **vaccine effectiveness** is $$1-R=91.67\%.$$

Comment: The answer cannot be 93.75% (15/16) since if you consider a population of 300 susceptible people with a vaccine coverage rate of 80% then 240 are vaccinated and 60 are non-vaccinated. If the efficacy is 15/16 then 240x(1 – 15/16)= 15 of the vaccinated fall sick. Add this to the 60 non-vaccinated who fall sick gives 15/(15+60)=0.2, or 20%, not the required 25%.

Comment: @DerekJennings Thanks for catching my original wrong answer $(93.75\%),$ which had arisen from a typo (I'd originally written $\frac14$ instead of the intended $\frac13$) in the final paragraph. The answer has been rectified. Reverse the downvote?

Comment: Downvote reversed, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a group of $n$ people all of whom are susceptible to the disease when not vaccinated, and let $e$ be the efficacy of the vaccine (expressed as $ 0 \le e \le 1 $ rather than as a percentage) and let $v$ ($0 \le v \le 1$) be the population coverage of the vaccine. Then the number of vaccinated people falling sick, $s$, will be given by

$$ s = nv \left( 1 – e \right) \quad (1)$$
and the number of non-vaccinated people falling sick, $\bar s,$ will be given by
$$ \bar s = n \left( 1 – v \right) . \quad(2)$$

In the question the vaccine coverage is $80\%$, and so $v=0.8$. If we denote by $p$ the fraction of people falling sick that are vaccinated then we have

$$ p = \frac{ s } {s+\bar s}.$$

We are also given that $p=0.25$ since $25\%$ of the people falling sick have been vaccinated. Using equations (1) and (2) we get

$$ p =\frac{ s } {s+\bar s} = \frac{nv \left( 1 – e \right)}{nv \left( 1 – e \right) + n \left( 1 – v \right)}.$$

And so

$$ p= \frac{v-ve}{1-ve} ,$$

whereby solving for $e$ we obtain

$$ e= \frac{v-p}{v\left( 1-p \right) }.$$

Plugging in $p=0.25$ and $v=0.8$,

$$e= \frac{0.8-0.25}{0.8 \left( 1 – 0.25 \right) } = \frac{11}{12} \text{ or about } 91.67\%.$$

We can verify this by considering a population of $300$ susceptible people. Since the vaccine coverage is $80\%$, $240$ are vaccinated and $60$ are non-vaccinated. As the vaccine effectiveness is $11/12$ then $ 240 \times \left( 1- 11/12 \right) = 20$ of the vaccinated fall sick, which we add to the $60$ who fall sick in the non-vaccinated portion. Hence the fraction of vaccinated among all the sick is $20/ \left(20+60 \right) = 0.25,$ as required. Note that I have replaced the word efficacy with effectiveness. This is because we normally talk about efficacy in a trial situation and effectiveness in a real world situation and since we are reverse-engineering to obtain $e$ the data is very likely to come from a real world situation.